# Set 2 colums after an update on a table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, triggers, sql-insert

So I am trying to to put in capital letter 2 fields from my table after an insert. So I created a trigger but since I want to update 2 fields, I am not sure how to exactly do this. This is what I did but I don't think it's the right way to do this. I want to set these 2 fields in capital letter when there is an insert.

Thank you :)

````sql
CREATE or ALTER TRIGGER majVilleClient
on client
instead of insert
as
begin
update client
set nom_client =upper(nom_client)
where nom_client in (select nom_client from inserted)
set nom_ville = upper(nom_ville)
where nom_ville in (select nom_ville from inserted) 
end```
````

Comment: This code is not at all correct and does not resemble a MySQL trigger _at all_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am infamiliar wth your rdms but sure it osn't MySQL, you should change that

But when your first update worked, yu can use the following.

```
CREATE or ALTER TRIGGER majVilleClient
on client
instead of insert
as
begin
update client
set nom_client =upper(nom_client)
,nom_ville = upper(nom_ville)
where nom_client in (select nom_client from inserted)
```

end

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, which you tagged your question with, you would use a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger, so you can change the values before they are written:

```
delimiter //

create trigger majvilleclient
before update on client
for each row
begin
    set new.nom_client = upper(new.nom_client);
    set new.nom_ville  = upper(new.nom_ville);
end;
//

delimiter ;
```

Comment: my first post with the first field only was working perfectly fine. I just wanted to add a second field to set in capital letter. It's not exactly what I am trying to do but thanks this one works too.

Answer (score 0):

Update that's what I did but I am not sure if this would works.

````sql
CREATE or ALTER TRIGGER majVilleClient
on client
after insert
as
begin
update client
set nom_client =upper(nom_client),
    nom_ville = upper(nom_ville)
where nom_ville in (select nom_ville from inserted) and nom_client in (select nom_client from inserted) 
end```
````